# How can I place two components in ScrollView, one being a cardView and other a recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am new to android and trying to make a profile section of a social media app. The profile section is a fragment and inside this I wanted to have a CardView to hold user's information and then a RecyclerView to show user's posts. I have tried implementing this using a ScrollView and putting insinde the cardView and RecyclerView. I wanted both cardView and RecyclerView to be scroll as one, but currently the cardView is at its place and only elements in recyclerView are scrolling.

**EDIT**
NestedScrollView kind of worked for me. But I also wanted overScrollMode to work fine while scrolling to the end.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.profile.ProfileFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            style="?attr/materialCardViewFilledStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="100dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/profileDisplayPicture"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/user_profile_picture"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/profileName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/profileCollegeInfo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.divider.MaterialDivider
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profileLinkedinBtn"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/linkedin"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_linkedin" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profileMailBtn"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/mail"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_gmail" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/profileRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try using NestedScrollView

Comment: @AshutoshOjha Thanks, scrolling is working fine. But overScrollMode is different for the recycler view and the whole ScrollView. I mean I want to make cardView and recyclerView as one so while reaching to the upper or lower extreme overScrollMode is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also add below line to the recyclerview

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```